# Why can I not take photos on my D90 when an external flash is attached?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d90

When I connect an external flash to my Nikon D90, the camera cannot take pictures. It is focusing but doesn't want to release the shutter. Also, the shutter speed and aperture numbers disappear from the LCD display.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this situation however it looks like the camera doesn't recognize the flash since there's no indication of an external speed light attached in the display. Have you tried it on a different body?

Comment: "The same" it is working like the other D90? Or "the same" it is not working like your original SB700 on your D90?

Comment: My d90 îs not working with SB 700 SB 600 SB 800

Comment: @cozanu I digged a little dipper but couldn't figure out the problem. However it worth to do a couple of things, first check to see if hot shoe contacts are firm and clean. Try a camera reset. Remove the lens and try to shoot in M mode both with camera and flash and with detached flash. The sb-700 display says it's connected to a camera with CLS capabilities but it can't read FL and aperture. However camera doesn't show a flash is attached and I think it seems to be working with popup but it's impossible since sb-700 blocks its way to fully rise.